# mysql reduce time taken for select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 700000 rows and 400 columns with a column id indexed and other columns are dynamic.

when I just give

```
select * from table
```

it takes more than 4 minutes. Table is with myisam engine and i tried increasing `key_buffer_size` which did not help much. What other parameters I can optimise to get it faster please

Comment: Identify the bottleneck. Likely culprits would be I/O (is this stored on a fast SSD or on a sluggish rotating platter?), transfer time (over the network?) and client processing of the result. And determine what acceptable performance should be. (How long should it take to return 280,000,000 values?)

Answer (score 5):

The biggest problem in running your query is simply populating the response. No matter what underlying efficiency is under the table, and even if there're very few fields that have data, you will have 400-cell record returned per each row you have in the table - so, you have to send 280M cells in 4 minutes, which means ~1M cells/sec.

key_buffer_size will do nothing, as you're just streaming your table (.MYD) file, which is not cached in key cache, and only OS buffers.

So, if you want to make it faster, you may either want to:

- reduce number of columns you read by not reading *, but specifying individual columns
- reduce number of columns you have in the table
- read fewer rows

If you don't want any of the above and want your workload to be faster, you have to do the reading in parallel.

If you're usually not filtering/indexing by values of your columns, you can have them in a BLOB field packed in any other way (Thrift, Protobufs, JSON, etc), that way reading that data will not cause the insane protocol overhead, and you will be able to read your table faster.

Comment: i will try loading it as blob, but it's an import of csv file which I want to make use later for ETL so the table needs all the rows and columns and I have to use '*'